# Sorry Something Went Wrong when List Item Submitted

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, list, error

We are using SharePoint 2013 on premises and have a list with a workflow attached.  When a user submits a list item, they should be redirected to a page with instructions/next steps.  Some users get redirected to the page no problem.  Other users it gives them a message "sorry something went wrong" but the list item still saves. (Everyone has the same level of permissions).  We had one user that received the error and when she tried entering the request again immediately after, it redirected to the page as designed.  The workflow completes as designed on all entries.  I looked up the correlation ID and the error indicates PageNotFoundError page is missing but it's there. We have multiple lists on this site and this is the only one that has the issue. Any ideas on what's causing the error?

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The system cannot find the file
>   specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002), StackTrace:
>       at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.GetWebPartPageContent(Uri pageUrl, Int32 pageVersion, PageView requestedView, HttpContext context,
>   Boolean forRender, Boolean includeHidden, Boolean mainFileRequest,
>   Boolean fetchDependencyInformation, Boolean& ghostedPage, String&
>   siteRoot, Guid& siteId, Int64& bytes, Guid& docId, UInt32& docVersion,
>   String& timeLastModified, Byte& level, Object& buildDependencySetData,
>   UInt32& dependencyCount, Object& buildDependencies,
>   SPWebPartCollectionInitialState& initialState, Object&
>   oMultipleMeetingDoclibRootFolders, String& redirectUrl, Boolean&
>   ObjectIsList, Guid& listId) 
>       at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPRequestModuleDataFetchWebPartPageInformationForInit(HttpContext
>   context, SPWeb spweb, Boolean mainFileRequest, String path, Boolean
>   impersonate, Boolean& isAppWeb, Boolean& fGhostedPage, Guid& docId,
>   UInt32& docVersion, String& timeLastModified, SPFileLevel& spLevel,
>   String& masterPageUrl, String& customMasterPageUrl, String& webUrl,
>   String& siteUrl, Guid& siteId, Object& buildDependencySetData,
>   SPWebPartCollectionInitialState& initialState, String& siteRoot,
>   String& redirectUrl, Object& oMultipleMeetingDoclibRootFolders,
>   Boolean& objectIsList, Guid& listId, Int64& bytes) 
>       at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPRequestModuleData.FetchWebPartPageInformation(HttpContext
>   context, String path, Boolean impersonate, Boolean& isAppWeb, Boolean&
>   fGhostedPage, Guid& docId, UInt32& docVersion, String&
>   timeLastModified, SPFileLevel& level, String& masterpageUrl, String&
>   customMasterPageUrl, String& webUrl, String& siteUrl, Guid& siteId,
>   Object& buildDependencySetData) 
>       at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPRequestModuleData.GetWebPartPageData(HttpContext
>   context, String path, Boolean throwIfFileNotFound) 
>       at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPVirtualFile.CalculateFileDependencies(HttpContext
>   context, SPRequestModuleData basicRequestData, ICollection&
>   directDependencies, ICollection& childDependencies) 
>       at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPDatabaseFile.EnsureDependencies(HttpContext
>   context, SPRequestModuleData requestData) 
>       at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPDatabaseFile.EnsureCacheKeyAndViewStateHash(HttpContext
>   context, SPRequestModuleData requestData) 
>       at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPDatabaseFile.GetVirtualPathProviderCacheKey(HttpContext
>   context, SPRequestModuleData requestData) 
>       at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPVirtualPathProvider.GetCacheKey(String
>   virtualPath) 
>       at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetCacheKeyFromVirtualPath(VirtualPath
>   virtualPath, Boolean& keyFromVPP) 
>       at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultFromCacheInternal(VirtualPath
>   virtualPath, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate) 
>       at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath
>   virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean
>   allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean
>   ensureIsUpToDate) 
>       at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext
>   context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean
>   allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean
>   throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate) 
>       at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVirtualPathObjectFactory(VirtualPath
>   virtualPath, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean
>   throwIfNotFound) 
>       at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(VirtualPath
>   virtualPath, Type requiredBaseType, HttpContext context, Boolean
>   allowCrossApp) 
>       at System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory.GetHandlerHelper(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath virtualPath, String
>   physicalPath) 
>      at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.MaterializeHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)     at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step,
>   Boolean& completedSynchronously)
>       at System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception
>   error) 
>       at System.Web.HttpApplication.BeginProcessRequestNotification(HttpContext
>   context, AsyncCallback cb) 
>       at System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
>   wr, HttpContext context) 
>       at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr
>   rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData,
>   Int32 flags) 
>       at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr
>   rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData,
>   Int32 flags) 
>       at System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr
>   pHandler, RequestNotificationStatus& notificationStatus) 
>       at System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr
>   pHandler, RequestNotificationStatus& notificationStatus) 
>       at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr
>   rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData,
>   Int32 flags) 
>       at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr
>   rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData,
>   Int32 flags)
>
> Application error when access
>   /functions/it/Pages/PageNotFoundError.aspx, Error=The file
>   /functions/it/_catalogs/masterpage/ErrorLayout.aspx does not exist.
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPRequestModuleData.GetWebPartPageData(HttpContext
>   context, String path, Boolean throwIfFileNotFound) 
>       at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPVirtualFile.CalculateFileDependencies(HttpContext
>   context, SPRequestModuleData basicRequestData, ICollection&
>   directDependencies, ICollection& childDependencies) 
>       at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPDatabaseFile.EnsureDependencies(HttpContext
>   context, SPRequestModuleData requestData) 
>       at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPDatabaseFile.EnsureCacheKeyAndViewStateHash(HttpContext
>   context, SPRequestModuleData requestData)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPDatabaseFile.GetVirtualPathProviderCacheKey(HttpContext
>   context, SPRequestModuleData requestData) 
>       at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPVirtualPathProvider.GetCacheKey(String
>   virtualPath) 
>       at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetCacheKeyFromVirtualPath(VirtualPath
>   virtualPath, Boolean& keyFromVPP) 
>       at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultFromCacheInternal(VirtualPath
>   virtualPath, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate) 
>       at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath
>   virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean
>   allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean
>   ensureIsUpToDate) 
>       at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext
>   context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean
>   allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean
>   throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate) 
>       at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVirtualPathObjectFactory(VirtualPath
>   virtualPath, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean
>   throwIfNotFound) 
>       at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(VirtualPath
>   virtualPath, Type requiredBaseType, HttpContext context, Boolean
>   allowCrossApp) 
>       at System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory.GetHandlerHelper(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath virtualPath, String
>   physicalPath) 
>       at System.Web.HttpApplication.MaterializeHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>
> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The file
>   /functions/it/_catalogs/masterpage/ErrorLayout.aspx does not exist.
>       at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPRequestModuleData.GetWebPartPageData(HttpContext
>   context, String path, Boolean throwIfFileNotFound) 
>       at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPVirtualFile.CalculateFileDependencies(HttpContext
>   context, SPRequestModuleData basicRequestData, ICollection&
>   directDependencies, ICollection& childDependencies) 
>       at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPDatabaseFile.EnsureDependencies(HttpContext
>   context, SPRequestModuleData requestData) 
>       at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPDatabaseFile.EnsureCacheKeyAndViewStateHash(HttpContext
>   context, SPRequestModuleData requestData) 
>       at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPDatabaseFile.GetVirtualPathProviderCacheKey(HttpContext
>   context, SPRequestModuleData requestData) 
>       at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPVirtualPathProvider.GetCacheKey(String
>   virtualPath) 
>       at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetCacheKeyFromVirtualPath(VirtualPath
>   virtualPath, Boolean& keyFromVPP) 
>       at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultFromCacheInternal(VirtualPath
>   virtualPath, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate) 
>       at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath
>   virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean
>   allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean
>   ensureIsUpToDate) 
>       at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext
>   context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean
>   allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean
>   throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate) 
>       at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVirtualPathObjectFactory(VirtualPath
>   virtualPath, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean
>   throwIfNotFound) 
>       at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(VirtualPath
>   virtualPath, Type requiredBaseType, HttpContext context, Boolean
>   allowCrossApp) 
>       at System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory.GetHandlerHelper(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath virtualPath, String
>   physicalPath) 
>       at System.Web.HttpApplication.MaterializeHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>
> Getting Error Message for Exception System.Web.HttpException
>   (0x80004005): Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException' was thrown.
>   ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The file /functions/it/_catalogs/masterpage/ErrorLayout.aspx does not exist. 
>       at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPRequestModuleData.GetWebPartPageData(HttpContext
>   context, String path, Boolean throwIfFileNotFound) 
>       at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPVirtualFile.CalculateFileDependencies(HttpContext
>   context, SPRequestModuleData basicRequestData, ICollection&
>   directDependencies, ICollection& childDependencies) 
>       at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPDatabaseFile.EnsureDependencies(HttpContext
>   context, SPRequestModuleData requestData) 
>       at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPDatabaseFile.EnsureCacheKeyAndViewStateHash(HttpContext
>   context, SPRequestModuleData requestData) 
>       at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPDatabaseFile.GetVirtualPathProviderCacheKey(HttpContext
>   context, SPRequestModuleData requestData) 
>       at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPVirtualPathProvider.GetCacheKey(String
>   virtualPath) 
>       at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetCacheKeyFromVirtualPath(VirtualPath
>   virtualPath, Boolean& keyFromVPP) 
>       at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultFromCacheInternal(VirtualPath
>   virtualPath, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate) 
>       at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath
>   virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean
>   allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean
>   ensureIsUpToDate) 
>       at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext
>   context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean
>   allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean
>   throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate) 
>       at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVirtualPathObjectFactory(VirtualPath
>   virtualPath, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean
>   throwIfNotFound) 
>       at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(VirtualPath
>   virtualPath, Type requiredBaseType, HttpContext context, Boolean
>   allowCrossApp) 
>       at System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory.GetHandlerHelper(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath virtualPath, String
>   physicalPath) 
>       at System.Web.HttpApplication.MaterializeHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>
> at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.MaterializeHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>
> at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) 
>        at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Comment: Could you please attach the ULS-Log (whole correlation).

Comment: Are you using SharePoint 2010 workflow or SharePoint 2013 workflow? What is the page with instructions/next steps? Is it a custom page or a built-in page? Please provide a screenshot about this page. In addition, to make sure workflow work well, you need to make sure the trigger has at least Edit permissions on all related lists of the workflow.

Comment: Is a new page created after saving of item?

Comment: I'm working on getting the error for you MHeld... We are waiting for the user to submit another entry to capture the right log.  We are a medical practice so it takes some time to get a response.  As for the other questions... the workflow works as designed, it's not a workflow issue.  The page it gets redirected to is just a page that was created in the site pages library and has a few sentences with next steps outlined. Hope that helps!

Comment: @MHeld I edited the original post and added the log entries.

Answer (score 0):

I had that kind of issue long time ago on SP13.

In your log you have the following message which help you:

> Getting Error Message for Exception System.Web.HttpException (**0x80004005**): Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException' was thrown. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The file **/functions/it/_catalogs/masterpage/ErrorLayout.aspx does not exist.**

Usually the error code **0x80004005** means an access denied.
So, may be your master page at that location**/functions/it/_catalogs/masterpage/ErrorLayout.aspx** is not published/approved with the major version. (If the master page catalog is still configured by default)

Comment: Thanks!  I checked that and it's published as a major version.  The weird thing is this does not happen to everyone, just sporadic users.

Comment: Do you any webpart querying data (XSL for rendering, js links, external contents/assets...) into your ErrorLayout.aspx page? If yes may be one of them is stored into a library/list configured with wrong perms or read only their own.

Comment: For the sporadic effect, if you have 2 or more front ends, a pointer could be the different version of the .Net Framework installed on them.